# MP4Box h264 merge video files

Tags: ffmpeg, merge, h.264, mp4box

I combine video with mp4box. Merge video corrupted.The first video correctly but others are corrupt. Sound properly, the video is corrupted. I know very little english :) Sorry...
MP4Box merge code:

```
MP4Box -force-cat -cat 1.mp4 -cat 2.mp4 -cat 3.mp4 out.mp4
```

Out.mp4 download [link](http://hqimages.net/out.mp4)

1.mp4

```
General
Complete name                            : 1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 229 MiB
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Overall bit rate                         : 2 136 Kbps
Movie name                               : 
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Bit rate                                 : 2 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 692 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.094
Stream size                              : 214 MiB (94%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 129 r2245 bc13772
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / ana                                                                                        lyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_                                                                                        range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_ps                                                                                        kip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=8 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0                                                                                         / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bf                                                                                        rames=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0                                                                                         / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_l                                                                                        ookahead=50 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qp                                                                                        min=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1                                                                                        .00
Language                                 : Turkish

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 132 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 83ms
Stream size                              : 14.1 MiB (6%)
Language                                 : Turkish
```

2.mp4

```
General
Complete name                            : 2.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 7.58 MiB
Duration                                 : 30s 38ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 116 Kbps
Movie name                               : 
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 30s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 692 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.094
Stream size                              : 7.10 MiB (94%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 129 r2245 bc13772
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : Turkish

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 30s 38ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 83ms
Stream size                              : 470 KiB (6%)
Language                                 : Turkish
```

3.mp4

```
General
Complete name                            : 3.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 229 MiB
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Overall bit rate                         : 2 138 Kbps
Movie name                               : 
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Bit rate                                 : 2 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 692 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.094
Stream size                              : 215 MiB (94%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 129 r2245 bc13772
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=8 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : Turkish

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 15mn 0s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 132 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : 83ms
Stream size                              : 14.2 MiB (6%)
Language                                 : Turkish
```

Out.mp4

```
General
Complete name                            : out.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 466 MiB
Duration                                 : 45mn 30s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 431 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-03-07 23:34:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-03-07 23:34:33

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 45mn 30s
Source duration                          : 30mn 30s
Nominal bit rate                         : 2 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 692 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.094
Source stream size                       : 436 MiB (94%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 129 r2245 bc13772
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=8 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : Turkish
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-03-07 23:34:34

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 45mn 30s
Source duration                          : 30mn 30s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Nominal bit rate                         : 132 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Source stream size                       : 28.7 MiB (6%)
Language                                 : Turkish
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-03-07 23:34:34
```

ffmpeg -i out.mp4

```
ffmpeg version N-50345-g50c2738-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 27 2013 17:02:21 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-filter=drawtext --enable-libfreetype --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
  libavutil      52. 17.103 / 52. 17.103
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 41.100 /  3. 41.100
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
**[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x17b6a20] multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome**
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2013-03-07 23:34:33
  Duration: 00:45:30.05, start: 0.009333, bitrate: 1431 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(tur): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x692 [SAR 1:1 DAR 320:173], 1999 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(tur): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

//Solved Problem

Problem: that 2-pass encoding. mp4box does not support 2-pass.

Comment: Have you tried using [avidemux](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/AviDemux) to append the video segments?  Also, if you can use a `.mkv` container, I believe the container itself allows for appending video files (via `mkvmerge`).

Comment: I tried avidemux now. I'm having the same problem with avidemux. video is corrupted. Why is the problem?

Comment: You can try converting the videos to .mpg and then concat them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you individually rip each file to exact same output setting using "Video to Video" from Media Converters. It does not matter if your input files are in different codecs/ format / container like avi, mkv, mp4, m4v or whatever. Video to video can handle different input formats for constant output format without any problems.

It does not matter what the output format is so long as they are all identical. Then simply append them using mkvmerge. It should go smoothly.